# Unable to retrieve full credit card number from a Stripe token

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I am trying to store and retrieve credit card information for later use using Stripe. Here is my code:

```
require_once('./stripe-php-8.3.0/init.php');

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'secret key'
);

$token = $stripe->tokens->create([
    'card' => [
        'number' => '4242424242424242',
        'exp_month' => 5,
        'exp_year' => 2023,
        'cvc' => '314',
    ],
    //'customer' => $cus_id,
]);
   
$new_token = $token['id'];

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($token);
echo "</pre>";

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($new_token);
echo "</pre> <br>Token Retrieval:<br>";

$get_token = $stripe->tokens->retrieve(
  $new_token,
  []
);

echo "<pre>";
print_r ($get_token);
echo "</pre>";
```

I am able to create the token, and retrieve it, but I am not able to retrieve the full credit card number, only the last four digits. This is the response I get:

```
[id] => tok_xxx
[object] => token
[card] => Stripe\Card Object
    (
        [id] => card_xxx
        [object] => card
        [address_city] => 
        [address_country] => 
        [address_line1] => 
        [address_line1_check] => 
        [address_line2] => 
        [address_state] => 
        [address_zip] => 
        [address_zip_check] => 
        [brand] => Visa
        [country] => US
        [cvc_check] => unchecked
        [dynamic_last4] => 
        [exp_month] => 5
        [exp_year] => 2023
        [fingerprint] => pM2Rf7okmFj0upYk
        [funding] => credit
        [last4] => 4242
        [metadata] => Stripe\StripeObject Object
            (
            )

        [name] => 
        [tokenization_method] => 
    )

[client_ip] ≥ 192.168.1.1
[created] => 1653547655
[livemode] => 
[type] => card
[used] =>
```

Which seems to be correct from the API documentation, but how do I retrieve the actual full credit card number?

Comment: Read the documentation of the API or ask their developers. If there is no way, then there is no way (and if there IS a way, the documentation will tell you)

Comment: Yeah, I obviously did but I seem to be missing something, this is why I am asking here.

Comment: And what did the vendor say?

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens?lang=curl

Comment: Don't tell me :) I'm not reading through this. Have you asked the vendor support as well?

Answer (score 2):

Card details such as the number or the CVC are protected by the [PCI Security Standards](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/). For that reason, Stripe will help you collect card details and store it securely in their systems and give you a "reference" to that card (a PaymentMethod id `pm_123` or a legacy Token id `tok_123`).

Stripe won't let you access the full card details and will instead expose useful information such as the card's brand, expiration date or last four digits. This is covered in their documentation around [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#validating-pci-compliance) or what their [API returns](https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide#out-of-scope-card-data).

In most cases, businesses shouldn't even have access to the card details themselves. They would use [Elements](https://stripe.com/payments/elements), a UI library from Stripe, with multiple ways to collect card details (and other payment method types) securely without ever accessing the card number. This lowers the PCI compliance burden of all those businesses and makes it easy to accept payments.

In your example, you're directly creating a card Token via the [API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card) server-side. This means your server has full access to this information. This puts you in a way higher scope for PCI compliance already which comes with strict rules on how your system should secure the data. But at this point you do have the card details and if you need it in the future you'd have to store this information separately yourself. It's discouraged for most businesses and usually a misunderstanding, but some need this and I don't know what your use-case looks like.